# How to change color like half and half in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create html table like calendar .
Some event is registered in calendar. and each event distinguish with it's color.

But I would like to change it's color like half and half cells.

[image]

my desired image is like this

[image]

Now my code is like this.
Event is binding with clicking.
is it possible? and How can I realize that?

If someone has experienced same issue,please let me know.

```
      $("#our_calendar td")     
      .click(function() {

          const green="rgb(0, 255, 0)";
          const yellow="rgb(255, 255, 0)";
          const transparent="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";
          const red="rgb(255, 0, 0)";
          const purple="rgb(255, 0, 255)";

          console.log($(this).css('background-color'));


          if ($(this).css('background-color') == transparent)
            changecolor(this.id, green);
          else if ($(this).css('background-color') == green)
            changecolor(this.id, yellow);
          else if ($(this).css('background-color') == yellow)
            changecolor(this.id, purple);
          else 
            changecolor(this.id, transparent);
      });

   function changecolor(id,color){
  $("#"+id).css("background-color",color);}
```

Comment: try using css linear gradient: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to DileepNimantha's solution, but with an instant cutoff:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 49%, yellow 1%, green 1%, green 50%);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following styles in your element.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, yellow 50%, green 50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 50% 50%, yellow 50% 50%);
```